# How to keep my pizza hot and crispy during transport

Tags: pizza, food-transport

I am planning to make pizza for my work potluck this year. I will be the second time.

I cook it fresh in my over 10 minutes away from work, and then put it in pizza boxes to transport.

My initial concern last year, was that the pizza stays warm. The first pizza has to wait about 18 minutes for the other pizza to cook, then the 10 minute drive to work.

to solve this problem, I immediately took the pizza out of the oven and placed it directly into a aluminum foil lined box. The catastrophic and unxpected side effect, was that the heat and humidity ruined the crispyness of the bottom of the crust, and the pizza was a soft and saggy and sad mess.

This year I need to improve. I need to keep the pizza warm and crispy!

My first improvement is to put the pizza in the box, on top of an elevated cooky cooling grate. This will allow the bottom to breath.

Now I am looking for ideas to deal with the humidity in the box.

Could I put something in there to absorb the humidity? Would a bunch of sheets of paper towel be good. Maybe I could go further and put a tonne of flour in the bottom? Maybe silica packets?

I am just looking for ideas to keep the pizza warm and crispy over about a 26 minute period.

Comment: related https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/61576. And take a look at <https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/38202, even though that one is about fried food.

Answer (score 1):

Pizza parlors have adapted to using thermal bags to slide the pizza boxes into and keep the pizza relatively warm. [One or two of these](https://restauranttory.com/royal-pizza-delivery-bag-roy-pza-bag-18?gclid=Cj0KCQiAuf7fBRD7ARIsACqb8w59BJFGtIQ31MbCvQoKur3Gf1esDVlnEj48KBmNqjucKUwEHsHDVXUaAgZBEALw_wcB) might be worth the investment. 18" square x 5" would be for larger pies, but you can get smaller bags, the 5" depth would hold two standard pizza boxes stacked on top of each other. There are a lot of similar products on the market which may work, but I linked a restaurant quality bag. Your local restaurant supply store may have them in stock (and most sell to the public).  The bags eliminate the worry about humidity, although many restaurants use a thick sheet of something similar to wax paper to prevent grease from bleeding through to the box.

Comment: those bags will keep the pizza warm, but will not keep it crispy as it will trap humidity.

Comment: You might try transporting it on a lightweight round rack inside the box so as to prevent the soggy bottom.

Comment: It might be worthwhile not to put them in the bag until it's time to leave. Having the pies in the boxes on top of the stove will keep them warm and the 10 minute drive shouldn't be long enough to make them soggy. Or, you could bake them a bit ahead and leave them in the oven on warm (very, very low setting) until just before you leave. Then box, bag, and go.  I like @suse idea for the rack... like a round coookie sheet(?), but I have no clue where you would get one.

Comment: @Max : I suspect that the reason for using cardboard boxes is that it will absorb some of the moisture, reducing (although not eliminating) the problem